# How to analyze the jmeter log?

Tags: jmeter

I am using "Indihiang" tool to understand the jmeter log, but the tool unable to recongnise it but it works fine for server logs so, help me to choose the tool to understand jmeter logs.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter log file (which is *jmeter.log*) doesn't contain any metrics which can be plotted as graphs.

In regards to .jtl results file - there are several options:

1. Using [JMeter Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
2. Using [JMeter Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners)
3. Using [Graphs Generator Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/#Graphs-Generator-Listener-supfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-1-3-font-sup) (available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/))
4. Using 3rd-party tool like [JAnalyser](http://janalyser.com/) or [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/)

Comment: thanks for the reply, iam running jmx file in window console i get jtl file